# <mat-select> multiple choice (formControl)

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript, angular-material

Im using Angular material's  for multipe choice purpose like mentioned in their site https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview (8th example). 
I also have an array of items (key and value) which are a part of the choices([key:1 value:extra cheese, key:2 value:onion])... I want them to be automatically selected (probably using formController) ... how can I do this?
plus, after the user selected/ unselectedsome options how do i get a new array back ?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ngModel

```
    <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings"
 multiple [(ngModel)]='defaultValue'>
```

and define this defulatValue in your component like this, or programaticly as you wish

```
defaultValue = [this.toppingList[1], this.toppingList[3]]
```

and you can get this variable when anything changes, it will contain your selected values. Took this example from material example, all works fine for me.

Comment: thanks! ill try it later and let you guys know if it works

Comment: i bet it will. lm i am glad to help